# Javascript equivalent function to PHP __call

Tags: javascript, php

Is there any function in javascript to do the same as the php function `__call`?

I wish I could do something like:

```
var obj = {
  __call: function(prop){
    console.log('Call obj.'+prop);
    return "fakeValue";
  }
}

obj.somePropertie // fakeValue
```

Obviously the goal is to not only log, but this is the idea

Comment: JavaScript has [getters and setters](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/) which offer a similar sort of syntactic sugar, but they're not what most people would consider "production ready". You're unlikely to encounter wide-spread support for them.

Comment: Look up the `Proxy` object. A fun API to toy with, but not production-ready.

Comment: no, ES6 might add stuff, but there is no method_missing in JS

Comment: You can give a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/RTThP/